# How can I highlight every div when I use jquery in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to highlight every div with jquery. I know you will have a very simple way to highlight it. But the challenge is I have over one thousands items, each item have a div and a specific id and I need to highlight each one. By the way, I need to put each item for each div because I allow each user to delete them individually. Can you help me to figure out how to achieve what I want? Appreciate.

```js
var id_item = $(".item").attr("id").split("_").pop();
        $("#result_"+id_item).css('background-color','yellow')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php $ids="1,2,3,4,5";

<div class="item" id="result_'.$id.'">lion</div>
<div class="item" id="result_'.$id'">tiger</div>
<div class="item" id="result_'.$id'">dog</div>
<!-- I will have thousands item-->
```

Comment: You want to highlight all items? When do you want to highlight them? Can't you just use css to set the background color?

Comment: Thanks for response. The reason I cannot use css is I need to use id, and id is include'.$id.',

Comment: Why do you need to use the id if al items should be highlighted? Is this some school homework?

Comment: yes, it is a project. I only can use id because I need to allow user to delete them individually when I use .remove() later on, for what I have learn so far, if I use class, I cannot remove them individually, right?

Comment: If you highlight all items, that's not highlighing; a highlight serves to emphasize a specific piece of content in order to draw attention to it, which is defeated if every piece of content on the page has the same 'highlight.' The way you're doing it is simply changing the background-colour, unless you've omitted some very relevant information for some reason.

Comment: why wouldn't you just do this with a css rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight them all

```
$(".item").css('background-color','yellow')
```

If you want to use id in your selector you can use regex selector like this

```
$('div:regex(id,result_[0-9]+)')
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But how about I want to use id. And the id include '.$id.'

Comment: so that is why I add a string $id into the id, so the id will be varied base on items, but then I don't know how to style it.

Comment: you should use classes to style your elements and use ids to change it (remove, modify, etc.)